# System boots but appears to crash shortly after loading the desktop

Tags: boot, display

I have a computer running Ubuntu 20.04 that appears to boot just fine until it makes it to the desktop. The boot process seems normal and the desktop loads initially, but after 5 to 10 seconds sitting on the desktop the screen flashes and goes black. After that point the system becomes completely unresponsive.

Once the screen goes black I lose the ability to SSH into the system, I can't pull up another terminal on the machine itself (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> etc), and the only way to restart it is to hold down the power button twice or physically remove power to the system.

The part that really makes this confusing is that the system works normally in recovery mode. I can boot the system to recovery mode, start a terminal to run `startx` and use it indefinitely. There are no issues with the screen going black, the networking shutting off, or the other terminals launching.

I've already tried reinstalling `gdm3` as well as `ubuntu-desktop`, I've tried updating packages and fixing broken packages from recovery mode, and I've even used recovery mode to reset the grub loader options.

I'm assuming there's some barrier between what regular desktop mode does and what recovery mode does, but I'm not sure where to start when figuring that out. Any help on the matter or even suggestions of what packages have control over blacking out the screen/locking down the system would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: It appears there are two separate desktops being launched at the same time. Both tty1 and tty2 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) have a desktop launched on them when the computer first starts up. tty1 launches to a lock/user selection screen, and tty2 launches to a logged-in desktop for my default user (which is the behavior I have configured).

EDIT 2: For context, the system is a desktop PC running a Ryzen 3 2200g and the iGPU from that chip on a Gigabyte B350 board. It's an install of Ubuntu I've had since about 2018. Adding some logs from `/var/log/syslog` from one of the recent boot ups into recovery mode. I'm seeing a lot of repetitions of this loop:

```
Nov 28 11:25:34 nastty systemd[1]: Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
Nov 28 11:25:34 nastty systemd[1]: gpu-manager.service: Succeeded.
Nov 28 11:25:34 nastty systemd[1]: Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Nov 28 11:25:34 nastty systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Nov 28 11:25:40 nastty systemd[1]: gdm.service: start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Nov 28 11:25:40 nastty systemd[1]: gdm.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Nov 28 11:25:40 nastty systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 28 11:25:40 nastty systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
Nov 28 11:25:41 nastty systemd[1]: gdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 19.
```

That doesn't appear in the normal boot cycle though, but I do see duplicates of what looks like the GPU boot process:

```
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty dbus-daemon[1571]: [session uid=1000 pid=1571] Activating service name='org.gnome.OnlineAccounts' requested by ':1.8' (uid=1000 pid=1676 comm="/usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor " label="unconfined")
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 8 Graphics (RAVEN, DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-132-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, initialising EGL layer.
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (==) AMDGPU(0): TearFree property default: auto
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (==) AMDGPU(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 using monitor section Configured Monitor
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 has no monitor section
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-1 has no monitor section
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-2 has no monitor section
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output DisplayPort-0
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-0
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-1
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID for output HDMI-A-2
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer: ACI  Model: 249a  Serial#: 87097
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Year: 2013  Week: 16
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID Version: 1.3
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Digital Display Input
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 52  vert.: 29
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Gamma: 2.20
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): DPMS capabilities: Off
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): redX: 0.641 redY: 0.338   greenX: 0.311 greenY: 0.619
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): blueX: 0.159 blueY: 0.059   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported established timings:
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 720x400@70Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 640x480@60Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 640x480@67Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 640x480@75Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@56Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@60Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@72Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 800x600@75Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 832x624@75Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 1024x768@60Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 1024x768@70Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 1024x768@75Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported standard timings:
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 960  refresh: 60  vid: 16513
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #2: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #3: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #4: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #5: hsize: 1920  vsize 1080  refresh: 60  vid: 49361
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #6: hsize: 1280  vsize 720  refresh: 60  vid: 49281
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #7: hsize: 1280  vsize 800  refresh: 60  vid: 129
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Supported detailed timing:
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): clock: 148.5 MHz   Image Size:  521 x 293 mm
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 2008  h_sync_end 2052 h_blank_end 2200 h_border: 0
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1084  v_sync_end 1089 v_blanking: 1125 v_border: 0
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Serial No: D4LMTF087097
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 24 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Monitor name: ASUS VS247
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID (in hex):
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #01100ffffffffffff0004699a2439540100
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #0111017010380341d782a2ac5a4564f9e28
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #0110f5054b7ef00714f814081809500b300
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #011d1c081c08100023a801871382d40582c
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #011450009252100001e000000ff0044344c
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #0114d54463038373039370a000000fd0032
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #0114b185311000a202020202020000000fc
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): #01100415355532056533234370a20200080
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing probed modes for output HDMI-A-2
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz UeP)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x59.9  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.9   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output DisplayPort-0 disconnected
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-0 disconnected
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-1 disconnected
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-2 connected
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using user preference for initial modes
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Output HDMI-A-2 using initial mode 1920x1080 +0+0
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): mem size init: gart size :bf7d6000 vram size: s:7e842000 visible:7e842000
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (==) AMDGPU(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (==) AMDGPU(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) Unloading modesetting
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) Unloading fbdev
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) Unloading fbdevhw
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) Unloading vesa
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: radeonsi
Nov 28 11:54:23 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: radeonsi
```

Then from shortly before the screen goes black this appears in the log:

```
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "ACI", prod id 9370
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "ACI", prod id 9370
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty dbus-daemon[1571]: [session uid=1000 pid=1571] Successfully activated service 'com.teamviewer.TeamViewer'
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty systemd-resolved[1099]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.0.1.
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "ACI", prod id 9370
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1440x900"x0.0   88.75  1440 1488 1520 1600  900 903 909 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)
Nov 28 11:54:28 nastty /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1584]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. There will generally be some reasons for the crash written to the system log. This can be accessed via the GUI with the Logs application, or via Terminal in `/var/log/syslog`. If you could [edit] your question to include some of the relevant logs, it may be possible to help identify the issue. If you could also include some information about your computer (brand, specs, etc.) and whether this is a new installation of Ubuntu or one you've used for a while, it may offer context 

Comment: I added some context above with the logs that looked relevant from `/var/log/syslog`, but I'm not sure why the recovery mode and normal boot sequences appear to go differently. Recovery mode doesn't boot a GUI at all on it's own, and normal mode boots two GUIs